# How can I assign a vector unknown function to solve the ODE system?

Tags: differential-equations, programming

I noted that using non-scalar variables is convenient when a system of differential equations is governed by a process that may be difficult to express symbolically. Taking a example from the [tutorial](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/AdvancedNumericalDifferentialEquationSolvingInMathematica/AdvancedNumericalDifferentialEquationSolvingInMathematica.pdf) on Page 6.

```
f[x_?VectorQ] := n^2*ListConvolve[{1, -2, 1}, x, {2, 2}, {1, 0}];
NDSolve[{X'[t] == f[X[t]], X[0] == (Range[n - 1]/n)^10}, X, {t, 0, 0.25}]
```

Obviously it does not work independently and requires the assignment of Vector variable **X**. Can anyone guide me how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the program as written works fine, but you forgot to define `n`.  I tried it for `n=3` and obtained credible results:

```
n = 3;
f[x_?VectorQ] :=  n^2*ListConvolve[{1, -2, 1}, x, {2, 2}, {1, 0}]; 
ans = X /. NDSolve[{X'[t] == f[X[t]], X[0] == (Range[n - 1]/n)^10}, X, {t, 0, 0.25}][[1]]
```

and, for instance, `ans[.2]` gives `{0.252832,0.584738}`.  Best wishes from one Tumbleweed recipient to another.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey, thank you. Oh... I realized my question was quite naive :)